# Easy jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to use one script to make an easy slider. Works perfect on jsfiddle but not when i copy/paste every parte on the web i'm making... What's the problem?
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```js
var $first = $('li:first', 'ul'),
    $last = $('li:last', 'ul');
$("#next").click(function () {
    var $next, $selected = $(".selected");


    $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
    $selected.removeClass("selected");
    $next.addClass('selected');
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    var $prev, $selected = $(".selected");

    $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
    $selected.removeClass("selected");
    $prev.addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
li {display:none}

.selected {display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<div>
<ul id="">
<li id="pic1"><img src="http://www.cooksmarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Pantry-Essentials-Lemons-400x250.jpg" alt="pic1"></li>
<li id="pic2"><img src="https://tendertummys.com/wp-content/uploads/tomatoes-2.jpg" alt="pic2"></li>
<li id="pic3"><img src="http://med.news.am/static/news/b/2014/08/3031.jpg" alt="pic3"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Dropbox link to the page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74509233/TEMP/LIST2.html)

Comment: Solution founded: missing   $(function () on the script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the DOM is ready before manipulating it.
Probably jsfiddle take care that the javascript get executed after the DOM became ready.
You have two options: move the script tag just before the body end tag or wrap your code in the $(document).ready() callback function which get called after the DOM becomes ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $first = $('li:first', 'ul'),
        $last = $('li:last', 'ul');

    $("#next").click(function () {
        var $next, $selected = $(".selected");

        $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
        $selected.removeClass("selected");
        $next.addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#prev").click(function () {
        var $prev, $selected = $(".selected");

        $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
        $selected.removeClass("selected");
        $prev.addClass('selected');
    });
});
```